# Linux Mint: External monitor (HDMI) works with the open source nouveau drivers but not nvidia-driver-460

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, linux-mint, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card

I've been having trouble getting my external monitors set up, and I finally got one to work by switching from the proprietary nvidia drivers to the open source ones. I'm on a Razer Blade 15 which is running a GTX 1060M.

I'm trying to achieve two things: figure out why the nvidia drivers won't detect my external displays, and at least get my 3rd display running on the open source drivers. My third display is plugged in to my USB-C thunderbolt port and I think it's recognized as display port.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The first monitor was my drivers, and the second monitor wasn't plugged in all the way (but also same driver issue.) What I did was purge my nvidia stuff with

```
sudo apt purge *nvidia*
```

I restarted and the display driver automatically changed from nvidia to nouveau, and I had the option to change to the latest nvidia drivers (in Driver Manager GUI). I clicked that to install them, restarted, and everything works :)

Hopefully this helps someone.